# Is it possible to have locomotive.js infinite loop when scrolling down?

Tags: locomotivejs, locomotive-scroll

I'm wondering if it's possible to make [locomotive.js](https://github.com/locomotivemtl/locomotive-scroll) infinite loop to the start of the content when you reach the bottom?